How can I shut off the water to my well system?
I'm not entirely sure how to go about shutting off my main water. From what I understand, there is a control box for the submersible pump and a shutoff between the pump and my pressure tank, but I do not see a main shutoff valve to the water supply into my house.
I am trying to replace an extremely corroded sharkbite connection to my water heater, but the only valve I see from the water heater shuts off supply to the upstairs.
To expand on the question, do I need to shut off my water pump, close the valve to my pressure tank, and drain the well tank all for a simple replacement at the water heater?
The first image is my pressure tank, it's shutoff valve, and the pressure switch. The second is the control box for my well pump.





You have three pictures.  The third looks like a gas water heater.  The inlet would be the blue connection on the right.  That has a shutoff valve.  So what's the problem?  I.e. why can't you use that shutoff.  Also, I've been told that those flexible cables are not intended for permanent installations.  A  plumber might tell you that both should be replaced with permanent metal piping.  That said, I have the same setup and haven't experienced problems with it yet.

@mdfst13 I'm probably the problem, but the cold line's shutoff valve runs between the water supply and upstairs. There's a supply line off to the left above the expansion tank that runs back to the pressure tank of my well system. Pardon my ignorance - does that line not bypass the shutoff valve at the water heater?

If the water pipe from the well comes to the top of the orange handle quarter turn valve on the blue cold side of the heater, that valve may be the cutoff for your whole house. Another picture from the right side of the heater may help diagnose this.

@Triplefault I added the side view of the water heater

Thanks. It seems that the old blackish copper pipe theoretically coming from the well also feeds up, as well as down to the orange handle valve. So turning the valve off may not cut off all water to your house. You'll have to turn off the pump and open a faucet to release the pressure.

@Triplefault  If I'm understanding correctly, then it probably IS a good idea to close the valve leading upstairs, in order to prevent backflow. But apart from that, turning off the power to the pump, and releasing pressure by opening a tap will probably be enough. I don't see the need for a main shut-off valve if all the pressure comes from the pump below everything else.

Yes, turning off both valves going upstairs would help prevent backflow. I suppose a master valve isn't technically necessary, but I'd put one in anyway, no need to wait for the pressure to dissipate in the event of a major water leak upstairs..

There doesn't appear to be a main shutoff in the pictures with the pressure tank and well pump controls. It appears that the red handle valve may be a hose bib. The water pipes above the orange handle valves for the water heater also feed up to other parts of the house, so they won't cut off water from the well completely.
Here's how you can cut off the water to the whole house:

Turn off power to the well pump.

Open the hot and cold water supplies at a faucet in the house.


With the pump power off, the pressure in the tank will dissipate, leaving no water able to come into the system from the well. You can then work on the plumbing.
When everything is back together again, turn the pump back on again.
Note that some well pump pressure switches have a low-pressure cutoff action, too, to save the ump if the water starts leaking fast. If your switch has this action, it will cut off the pump power when the water all runs out. You'll need to know how to reset the pressure switch so the well pump will start running again.
